# SaaS solution vs. On premise solution - should look and feel the same?

Tags: examples, lookandfeel

Currently I'm working on a SaaS IT product,that provides users a solution as a service.
User logs into our SaaS portal, defines his terms of use (hours, days, months), pays, and starts using. During his work, the user will be informed regarding his license consumption (with a cart area per project or with relevant alerts regarding his usage). Pay as you go approach, as I see it, effects the way we plan our products (functionality and UX).
It has recently been decided that this SaaS product will be also available on premise addition as well, which means, local installation needed first, different licensing and pricing model, and maybe differences on the functionality as well.
These 2 additions needs to co exist and according to our stakeholders, "Look and feel the same, like one product". Do they? can anyone think of an example? 2 additions of a product - same look and feel (experience)? 
I don't think it's mandatory, each use case (and SaaS is a whole other use case) deserves its own solution that serves its functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: In principle i agree these use cases should not be diffirent but can you elaborate more on what the on premise solution encompasses. I think your question needs to be a bit more clear and specific

Comment: So not clear.  How do they fit functionally and technically?  This is SaaS you sell as service or one that you are a customer?